# For loop inside switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to run a for loop inside one of my switch case.

```
case POINTS:
      return {

        ...state,
        totalPoints: action.user_points[0].singular_point


      }
```

So here `action.user_points[0]` has to start with 0 and should go all way upto 10. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `slice` out the first 10 elements in the array and then `reduce` all the `singular_point` values into one value.

```
case POINTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    totalPoints: action.user_points
      .slice(0, 10)
      .reduce((acc, point) => acc + point.singular_point, 0)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do the syntax and make an example. You can fix the code follow your requirement

```
case POINTS: {
  let totalPoints = 0
  for(let i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
    totalPoints += action.user_points[i]
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    totalPoints
  }
}
```